# Template engine with CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, pug, template-engine, coffeekup

I found the following template engines with CoffeeScript

- https://github.com/mauricemach/coffeekup (last commit 2 years ago)
- https://github.com/sstephenson/eco (last commit 2 years ago)
- https://github.com/ddopson/jade-coffeescript (last commit 4 month ago)

Now, I just wonder whether there some other template engines around with CoffeeScript, because the two first engines above were not updated since 2 years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for something more up-to-date, I'd suggest [ECT](https://github.com/baryshev/ect). I haven't really used it before, so I can't offer much advice, but several of my friends strongly recommend it.